# MySQL problem - Invalid column name?

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please help - I'm about ready to tear out my hair over this one ;(

Invalid column name '%Discover%'.

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_course_sections WHERE summary LIKE "%Discover%" AND course = 22
```

I'm looking for 'Discover' - but why is it treating it as a column???

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Put it in single quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM mdl_course_sections WHERE summary LIKE '%Discover%' AND course = 22
```

Comment: ah nipples... that simple huh? well,I'm thick. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

try ' instead of " for values.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `mdl_course_sections` WHERE `summary` LIKE '%Discover%' AND `course` = 22
```